# no sound after call a method - setVideoProfile()

Tags: javascript, frontend, agora.io

I have a problem, after subscribe to a remote stream I call a method - *setVideoProfile()* then there is no sound after that

```
this.client.on('stream-subscribed', (event) => {
     let remoteStream = event.stream;
     remoteStream.play(bindTag, {fit: 'contain'});
     remoteStream.setAudioVolume(100);
     remoteStream.setVideoProfile('120p_1');
});
```

when I comment `//remoteStream.setVideoProfile('120p_1');` the sound works

I use AgoraRTC v2.8.0

has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setAudioVolume](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#setaudiovolume) accepts only a number in the range [0,100] - both inclusive

Setting 0 mutes the audio and setting to 100 is maximum volume.

You can't pass in an arbitrary string like '120p_1'. That's why you do not hear any sound.

**Update** *(from comments below)*
You cant' set video profiles on remote streams. You can set this only on local streams. You should instead use dual streams and set a fallback mode if you want the user to receive a low-quality version of the remote video

```js
client.enableDualStream(function() {
  console.log("Enable dual stream success!")
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});

// Configuration for the receiver. When the network condition is poor, receive audio only. 
client.setStreamFallbackOption(remoteStream, 2);
```

see full documentation:

- video fallback https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/fallback_web?platform=Web
- dual streams https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#enabledualstream

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote wrong sample code :(
I corrected it. 

I untested that `setAudioVolume()` takes only integer,
but I pass the correct parameter to `setVideoProfile()`
[https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.stream.html#setvideoprofile

Comment: Oh. I see. You cant' set video profiles on remote streams. You can set this only on local streams. You should instead use dual streams if you want the user to receive a low-quality version of the remote video https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#enabledualstream